# How to detect default drag event of browsers using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose there is some text in the browser. If we select the text, all the browsers allow dragging it where we can even see the dragged text. Now I need to know when the user dragged the text. It can be partial text also.

Comment: Do you you wanna know when the user select and drag some text **from** your page or **into** your page?

Comment: @BatuZet actually from one div to another div

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect if the user drags some text from somewhere into one of your elements in your page and not allow it, you can try storing that element's value in some global var on `keyup` function and passing this value to it again on `mouseenter` action.

```
var buff = "";
$("input[name=buff]").on("keyup", function(){
    buff = $(this).val();
});
$("input[name=buff]").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).val(buff);
});
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRmJ5/3/)** and try dragging some text into textbox. It's not working for IE9 but you can do some extra events to detect that.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be pretty simple:

```
  xyz.bind('dragover', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        xyz.bind('drop', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Dropped");
            return false;
        });
```